# For Loop iteration for Multiple Gains , which create multiple output corresponding to Gains(G1,G2,G3,G4,G5)

Tags: python-2.7

Can anybody suggest what is the error in for loop.How to run successfully the below for loop ?

if(testNum==1):

```
print ("Eneter the Step up voltage (pu)")
Vstepup = raw_input("Vstep_up : ")
Vstepup=float(Vstepup)
print ("Eneter Regulator Gain(G1,G2,G3,G4,G5)")
Gain_list=[G1,G2,G3,G4,G5]
G1 = raw_input("G1 : ")
G2 = raw_input("G2 : ")
G3 = raw_input("G3 : ")
G4 = raw_input("G4 : ")
G5 = raw_input("G5 : ")
G1=int(G1)
G2=int(G2)
G3=int(G3)
G4=int(G4)
G5=int(G5)
```

# Run For loop for Multiple Gains G1,G2,G3,G4 and G5.

```
for index in enumerate(Gain_list):
p.case(nm+'_CONV.sav')
p.rstr(nm+'.snp')
p.strt(0,Gain_list+'Step_Up.out')
p.run(0, 0.2,100,1,0)
p.change_swsmod_con(SVCbus,Model_name,2, G)
p.change_swsmod_var(SVCbus,Model_name,2, Vstepup)
p.run(0, 0.8,100,1,0)
p.change_swsmod_var(SVCbus,Model_name,2, 1.0)
p.run(0, 1.0,100,1,0)
```

Comment: Please re-format your code to understand what is going on there.

Comment: How to call this Variable "Gain_List" inside for loop ?

Comment: I don't see your code properly (no indents), therefore I cannot help you.